# GeoFire Find user in near location and increase radius

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, geofire

i create this method for find near users , when this method called found near user if user is not near then increase and call it self again , but i want to set limit user 5 km , problem is when i set limit the available users are not showing ..
this code without set limit it work perfectly

```
    int radius=0;     //radius=0
    String driverId;  //driverId=null
    boolean driverFound=false;

//This Method Find Near Dear
void FindDriver(final LatLng theLocation){
    DatabaseReference mRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(DriverType);
    GeoFire geoFire=new GeoFire(mRef);
        GeoQuery query=geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(theLocation.latitude,theLocation.latitude),radius);
        query.removeAllListeners();
        query.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {

            //When this method find driver call antoher method and finish this activity   
            @Override             
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location){
                if(!driverFound){
                    driverFound=true;
                    driverId=key;
                    SetDriver(driverId)}

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {}
            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {}
            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                if(!driverFound){
                    radius++;
                    FindDriver(theLocation);    //Method Call it self and increase the radius if driver still not found
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
   }
```

this is another method where i set limit

```
    int radius=0;     //radius=0
    String driverId;  //driverId=null
    boolean driverFound=false;

//This Method Find Near Dear
void FindDriver(final LatLng theLocation){
    DatabaseReference mRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(DriverType);
    GeoFire geoFire=new GeoFire(mRef);
        GeoQuery query=geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(theLocation.latitude,theLocation.latitude),radius);
        query.removeAllListeners();
        query.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {

            //When this method find driver call antoher method and finish this activity   
            @Override             
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location){
                if(!driverFound){
                    driverFound=true;
                    driverId=key;
                    SetDriver(driverId)}

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String key) {}
            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {}
            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                if(!driverFound){
                    if(radius<5){
                       radius++;
                       FindDriver(theLocation);    //Method Call it self and increase the radius if driver still not found
                     }else{
                       Dismiss();
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No Near Driver",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
   }
```

may be there i use another logic , but i don't know how , please help me ,
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: it should be obvious why the are no results: `int radius = 0` ...maybe start with `1` ?

Comment: @MartinZeitler i also try to set radius =0 , radius = 2, but the problem is same.

Comment: Set the radius to some maximum distance (e.g. 10km), then in `onKeyEntered` maintain a list of Driver(key,location,distanceToTheLocation) and in `onGeoQueryReady` sort the List<Driver> (by distanceToTheLocation) and use the closest Driver.